# Pandas with columns of lists. How to create new dataframe with grouping first elements, second elements, etc

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Consider this dataframe called `df_b`

|  | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [1, 2, 3] | [4, 5, 6] | [7, 8, 9] | [10, 11, 12] |
| 1 | [13] | [14] | [15] | [16] |

Each row may contain different length lists, however the length for a single row must be the same for each column.  I am trying to unroll the dataframe, but not using `explode` which creates all combinations.  Instead the output I am looking for is:

|  | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 4 | 7 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 8 | 11 |
| 2 | 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 |
| 3 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |

where the first row would result in 3 rows being generated (length of list is 3) and the second row would result in 1 row being generated (length of list is 1).  Is there a single pandas function which would do this or would this require a combination of operations?

Comment: `df_b.explode(list(df_b.columns))`

Comment: Ah yes, I was using pandas 1.2.1 but I thought I was using a newer version.  The above command, which now works for me, is 1.3 and above